# Downcast error in query

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to delete object using a query. However I am getting an downcast error saying Downcast from [PFObject] only unwraps optionals did you mean to use !?

```
 var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.whereKey("deleteID", containsString: selectedObjId)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        for object in (objects as! [PFObject]) {

            if error == nil {
                //Hide activity indicator and go back to collection view when done deleting
                object.delete() // 削除
                self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
                self.quitButtonPressed()

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the returning `objects` is of type `[PFObject]?` so instead of down casting just unwrap the object

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
      for object in objects! {
         do {
           //Hide activity indicator and go back to collection view when done deleting
           try object.delete() // 削除
         } catch let error as NSError {
           print(error)
         }
      }
      self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
      self.quitButtonPressed()
  } else {
    print(error!)
  }
}
```

You should also check if the error is nil **before** the repeat loop and the lines to hide the indicator and press the button are supposed to be executed once **after** the repeat loop.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer I still get an error at object.delete() saying call can throw but it is not marked with try and the error is not handled. I am trying to delete an object from posts class. I want it so that if the objectID and the deletesID matches it would delete the object using a query.

Comment: Please read the chapter about the new error handling of Swift 2 in the Language Guide. I updated the answer to conform to the new syntax.